# Can you negate comparisons by negating each individuals expression?

Tags: logic

For example the negation of $(expression1) < (expression2)$ is $ (expression1) >= (expression2)$ but can you say that the negation is: $not(expression1) <  not(expression2)$? Similarly with other comparison operators like "="?

Comment: What about $3 > 4$? Is $not(3) > not(4)$? What should $not(3)$ even mean?

Comment: Can you define $<$ as a relation on boolean expressions? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @BobKrueger sorry, I confused this with another question. I do intend on meaning not(3) to be -3, that was my original question.

Comment: @BobKrueger < as a relation of boolean expressions in defined in c++, by the way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143976/is-the-operation-false-true-well-defined

Comment: That's what I would expect, since $\text{True}$ is usually identified with $1$, and $\text{False}$ with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: $3 < 3$ is false, but $-3 < -3$ is also false.